# Duda sobre cabeceras angular

Tags: angular, jwt

tengo una pequeña duda, tengo un servicio que intercepta el token y añade una cabecera llamada authorization con token, pero cuando voy a ver la cabecera aparecer como Bearer null, quisiera saber como podria arreglar este error y a que se debe y en que puede afectar.

token-interceptor

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req, next) {
    const tokenReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`,
      },
    });
    return next.handle(tokenReq);
  }
```

Asi obtengo el token:

```
    getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
```

El token me guarda pero en el navegador me sale null en la cabecera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Confirma en el interceptor que verdaderamente `getToken` no sea null con un `console.log`

Comment: Si, llega como null

Comment: Entonces es problema de tu servicio. Por alguna razon no esta retornando el token.

Comment: Me parece algo raro, yo estoy generando el token al momento de que el login sea correcto y me lo está guardando en el localStorage.

Comment: Debuguea desde la propiedad `getToken()`. Revisa primero que verdaderamente este cargando con `localStorage.getItem('token')`. También que cuando guardes en el local storage no haya espacios en el nombre del item. Y vete con `console.log` hasta ver que esta pasando.